# Trying to get AJAX field to update with returned value (But have to click away before it updates)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

[Image of form that uses AJAX & JS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MbMhP.png)

I've currently got a maintainer that uses AJAX so when I type a number into the "Order No" field the "Calc" field then gets updated with the "Account" associated with the Order No. It all works however the "Calc" field doesn't fill with the account number until a click away from the Order No field has been done which means that if you were to press the enter key after typing the number the calc is still blank when the checks were made to see if the account and calc numbers are the same.. If you were to type the number then click the "Accept" button the update is then done so the checks then work as expected. So I was wondering if there is a way so that this field could get updated without an extra click.

One solution I came up with was by doing the checks such as account==calc and calc != "" twice so it would run a function where the check would always say that the calc field is blank (as it hasn't updated at this point) which would return an alert saying "Blank" then after returning the alert it would run another function which is exactly the same to do the check again and this time it would work as expected but once the alert is taken out its as if it hasn't got that moments wait which allows for the Calc field to be updated in time.

Its hard for me to post all the code as I use a system that does all the AJAX behind the scenes for you but let me try explain how the AJAX works. Whatever you put in the Order No field will be sent to an external retrieval application that would check to see what account number is associated with the order no and then return it to the Calc field. If then the account and the calc field numbers match submit the form else say its an incorrect order number for that specific customer.

Here are the two JavaScript functions:

```js
function testerRun() {
    var abc = ('${row.CUSN760?html}').toString();
    var def = document.getElementById("CALCULA001").value;
    if (abc == def && abc != "") {
        //alert("Order Number & Account Number Match!");
        document.getElementById('FORM_M07052').submit();
        return true;
    } else if (document.getElementById('ORDN760').value == "") {
        document.getElementById('FORM_M07052').submit();
        return true;
    } else {
        //alert("Blank First Step!");
        finalStep();
    }
}

function finalStep() {
    if (document.getElementById("CALCULA001").value == "") {
        alert("Customers Account Details Need Amending..");
        return false;
    } else {
        var abc = ('${row.CUSN760?html}').toString();
        var def = document.getElementById("CALCULA001").value;
        if (abc == def && abc != "") {
            //alert("Order Number & Account Number Match!");
            document.getElementById('FORM_M07052').submit();
            return true;
        } else if (document.getElementById('ORDN760').value == "") {
            document.getElementById('FORM_M07052').submit();
            return true;
        } else {
            alert("Order Number & Account Number Do Not Match!");
            return false;
        }
    }
}​
```

And here is where the script is called:

```html
<input class="btn btn-primary accept" id="btnaccept" name="btn_accept" onclick="testerRun();return false" type="submit" value="Accept" />
```

@Shreyas Sorry there is no blur or change as im using a system called MRC and so they use behind the scenes AJAX scripts to handle thigns like this what I don't have access too so I need some sort of work around. Its only an issue when the user clicks enter in the order no field after entering the order number without doing anything else on the form as it doesn't update until the order number is deselected.

```js
document.getElementById('ORDN760').onkeydown = function(event){
    if (event.which == 13 || event.keyCode == 13) {
        document.getElementById('ORDN760').blur();
        testerRun();
    }
}
```

Function call not working though doesn't seem to do anything just sits there after blur.

Comment: I don't think you have posted the relevant code. This is the code that does the final Accept. There will be some code which is listening for the "change"  or "blur" event on the Order No field. Can you post that.

Comment: @Shreyas I've added the code I can for you sorry if its still not any good it would be impossible for me to be more specific than that.

Comment: So if I understand you right, you want to ensure that when the user presses Enter, the Calc field should get populated?

Comment: @Shreyas It's so when they click enter the Calc field should get populated before the javascript check as at the moment it doesn't get chance to update before the script is ran and submitted.

Comment: I've updated my answer so the form doesn't get submitted when you press the Enter key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a keypress handler on the Order No field, which listens for the Enter key, and submits the form when Enter is pressed.

```
document.getElementById('ORDN760').onkeydown = function(event){
    if (event.which == 13 || event.keyCode == 13) {
        document.getElementById('ORDN760').blur();
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: This has got me much closer to the solution I think. I will put the code above to show you how I have used your function. Only issue is I don't need to submit from there or return false after the blur I have tried to run another function called testerRun(); as this would handle the submit anyway once it has done the checks however it seems to be running the blur code but not the function call afterwards.

Comment: This wasn't the exact answer however the way of listening for the users key press and returning false if the key was press was what solved the issue for me. In the end I made it so when the enter button is pressed it returns false and so does not submit. This forces the end user to click the submit button which gives the ajax time to run.